# Beta App has been approved but the App is still "In Review"?

Tags: ios, xcode, review

Beta App has been approved by Apple, does this mean that the App will be approved also in App Store?

p.s when they approve Beta App that means it's an app in TestFlight where external users can test it, what im asking is that if they approved for external users does this mean that they will approve also for App Store.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Beta App? Approved, but not for the AppStore? What?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth when they approve Beta App that means it's an app in TestFlight where external users can test it, what im asking is that if they approved for external users does this mean that they will approve also for App Store.

Comment: So then specify that in your post. Also, your question is not about programming or tools related to programming.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all Test-flight is Optional.

I don't think app will be approved in Final review even-though Beta app review has been approved.

But [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#beta-testing) says ofCourse Beta app also reviewed under guidelines.But may be it could be a short review.

> Any app submitted for beta distribution via TestFlight should be
>   intended for public distribution and should **comply with the App Review
>   Guidelines**.

May be or May not be,But `Final review` is the final result.